# Auto generate user email while registration

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, user-registration

Here is the problem we are facing, we have a woocommerce website,
most of our customers don't have an email or can't remember their username, so we have to make them do every thing with their phone number, we tried a plugin called Digits which didn't work for us.

We have 2 options

a- Make the username as phone number but this way the comments on the store will show phonenumbers of users (which isn't a good idea).

b- Autogenerate email of the user while registration.

It should be like this:

1-Disable email verification in (register, login, profile, checkout)

2-Rename the Email field to "Phone or Email".

3- when user submits the form in (register, login, profile, checkout), if the text entered in the field it's an email don't do anything, else "@domain.com" will be added to the text.

I have checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45516597/username-auto-generated-by-billing-complete-name-in-woocommerce-registration) which is kinda similar but reversed.

any ideas on how to do so, please..